# Preg_replace Tag Replace Dashes With HTML Tag

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I am partially disabled. I write a LOT of wordpress posts in 'text' mode and to save typing I will use a shorthand for emphasis and strong tags. Eg. I'll write `-this-` for `<em>this</em>`.

I want to add a function in wordpress to regex replace word(s) that have a pair of dashes with the appropriate html tag. For starters I'd like to replace `-this-` with `<em>this</em>`

Eg:

`-this-` becomes `<em>this</em>`

`-this-.` becomes `<em>this</em>.`

What I can't figure out is how to replace the bounding chars. I want it to match the string, but then retain the chars immediately before and after.

```
 $pattern = '/\s\-(.*?)\-(\s|\.)/';
 $replacement = '<em>$1</em>';
 return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

...this does the 'search' OK, but it can't get me the space or period after.

Edit: The reason for wanting a space as the beginning boundary and then a space OR a period OR a comma OR a semi-colon as the ending boundary is to prevent problems with truly hyphenated words.

So pseudocode: 
1. find the space + string + (space or punctuation)
2. replace with space + open_htmltag + string + close_htmltag + whatever the next char is.

Ideas?

Comment: Why is the space and period even in the pattern?

Comment: If your doing this for fun/learning, then ignore this, but I'd probably suggest saving yourself from reinventing the wheel and include an existing markdown parser (there are plenty of open source ones such as https://github.com/erusev/parsedown) if your planning on creating/supporting a plugin.

Comment: Is there any need to escape `-`?

Comment: Not doing it for 'fun'. As I wrote above this is very practical. Having a working solution will -literally- save me an hour a week (and a lot of discomfort.) Typing out all these html tags is annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > a space as the beginning boundary and then a space OR a period OR a comma OR a semi-colon as the ending boundary

You can try with capturing groups with `<em>$1</em>$2` as substitution.

```
[ ]-([^-]*)-([ .,;])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dF0lJ7/10)

sample code:

```
$re =      "/-([^-]*)-([ .,;])/i";
$str = " -this-;\n -this-.\n -this- ";
$subst = '<em>$1</em>$2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

*Note:* Use single space instead of `\s` that match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

Edited by o/p: Did not need opening space as delimiter. This is the winning answer.

---

You can try with *Positive Lookahead* as well with only single capturing group.

```
-([^-]*)-(?=[ .,;])
```

substitution string: `<em>$1</em>`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dF0lJ7/12)

Comment: I think the solution you posted in the Comment works with one slight adjustment. It's no longer necessary to have the opening space as a delimiter. If you edit your Answer to reflect your Comment link I'll mark it as the correct answer. THANKS!

Comment: I'm not the OP, I'm just a random observer ;) It looks fine if you assume that the sequence starts with a space, otherwise it fails:)

Comment: I like the one using lookahead, it matches this `-this- or -this- becomes an some-this or -this-.` and doesn't count on space at the beginning +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(-)(.*?)(-)
```

Check the substitution section:

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/nB0eE3/3)**

[image]

**Edit**: as an improvement you can also use `-(.*?)-` and utilize capturing group `\1`

Comment: why do you need capturing groups for `-`? why do you need to escape `-`?

Comment: @user3218114 it's a regex trick (or technique) to do a text substraction. As you can see in the substitution section I use group 2 and discard 1 and 3 that contains the dash. On the other hand, I need to escape dash because it's special character for regex range (although I think is not needed).

Comment: special character only when used inside `[...]` for e.g `[a-z0-9]`. It you are not using the captured groups in the final string then no need to capture it.

Comment: @user3218114 yup, you are right. It's not needed. I'll update the answer, thanks for point that

Comment: This fails if you have this sequence `-this- or -this- becomes some-this or -this-.`

Comment: It's worth reading [The Elements of Good Regex Style](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html)

Comment: @user3218114 very nice, didn't notice it. Thanks for the link I'll read it right now.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, the regex pattern will start at a hyphen and collect any non-hyphen characters until the next hyphen occurs. It then wraps the collected text in an `em` tag. The hyphens are discarded.

Note: If you use a hyphen for its intended purposes, this may cause problems. You may want to devise an escape character for that.

```
  $str = "hello -world-. I am -radley-.";

  $replace = preg_replace('/-([^-]+?)-/', '<em>$1</em>', $str);

  echo $str; // no formatting
  echo '<br>';
  echo $replace; // formatting
```

Result:

```
hello -world-. I am -radley-.

hello <em>world</em>. I am <em>radley</em>.
```